# Can I show my Terms and Conditions in the Consent Page In Identity Server 4?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer4 to implement Authentication and Authorization. I need to show Terms and Condition page and also to capture whether the user has accepted it or not.

Can I use the Consent Page in the Identity Server flow to show my Terms and Conditions?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the **QuickStart\Account** controller code/view as you like, so it is possible to integrate a custom T&C page or logic in that page.

The alternative is to have the T&C as a "**scope**" that the user needs to "**select**", but using a scope, you can then associate some UserClaim with that.